# CRUD for user management with asp.net core mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have managed to create CRUD controllers and views for each table/entity.

I have a problem with user table. This entity is a derivated class from IdentityUser.

I cannot insert or update this kind of entity.

What is the best way to make CRUD operations on this user table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do everything for users via the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager class assuming you are using Identity.

Comment: Thanks but i am talking about CRUD management operations for administrator

Comment: Thats what I use for my management of users in the backend.  For example to pull a list of users I call the UserManager.Users.  I have also setup virtual navigation properties for Roles, Claims and Logins in order to get them in one query.  To create a new user in my backend again I just use UserManager.CreateAsync and then iterate through the selected roles and add them to the newly created user via AddToRoleAsync